# Chatview with list of view Nativescript vue

Tags: vue.js, listview, nativescript

I would like to do a chatView with Native-vue and for that I use List of view with dynamic array. I have a problem, I don't know how I can fix one view on the left or right side ?

Comment: Can you post code of what you've attempted?

Answer (score 0):

My code is like this:

````
        <ListView class="disposition" row="0" col="1" for="Message in messages" style="height:1250px" @itemLoading="DisplayMessage" >
            
                <v-template>
                    <label> hey</label>
                    <StructMSG :class="Message.theme" col="0" top="50" bottom="50" :info="Message"/> 
                </v-template >

                <v-template if="$odd">
                    <StructMSG :class="Message.theme" col="0" top="50" bottom="50" :info="Message"/>
                </v-template>

        </ListView>```
    In the Array "messages" there are the list of message of chat and I difference sender or reciver with element theme in my array. And I would like to display on left side if it's sender or right side if it's me.
````

Answer (score 0):

It's good I did it like this:

````
                    <v-template >
                        <Gridlayout columns="*,*">
                                <StructMSG v-if="Message.theme == 'theme1'" :class="Message.theme" col="0" top="50" bottom="50" :info="Message"/>
                                <StructMSG v-else :class="Message.theme" col="1" top="50" bottom="50" :info="Message"/>
                        </Gridlayout>
                    </v-template>
        </ListView>```
````